# Striped Fill in new Google Visualization API

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, bar-chart

Is there currently an option in the new Google Visualization API for adding a striped fill to a bar in a bar (or column) chart? What I am looking for is something similar to the chart fill (chf) option from the old image style:

```
&chf=b2,ls,85,C0C0C022,0.05,4F4F4F22,0.05
```

This code gives me the following in the old Image Charts API:

[image: Hashed columns]

I am wondering if this is possible in the new API?

Many thanks!

Comment: As far as I am aware, striped fills are not yet possible in the API.  You can make a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support for this, if you want to.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case but wanted to check and see if there was some sort of hack to make it work. Thanks anyway.